# Parsing tweet data with Python

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweets

I am trying to parse the tweet data for the follow fields and I also indicate the structure of the info in bracket:

- Actual text of the tweet: (statuses > text)
- Hashtag: (statuses > entities > hashtags > text)
- Screen name: (statuses > entities > user_mentions > screen_name)
- Location: (statuses > user > location)

Codes as follows:

```
q = '#hashtag'
count = 100

search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)
statuses = search_results['statuses']

status_texts = [status['text']
    for status in statuses ]

screen_names = [user_mention['screen_name']
    for status in statuses
        for user_mention in status['entities']['user_mentions'] ]

hashtags = [hashtag['text']
    for status in statuses
        for hashtag in status['entities']['hashtags'] ]

location = [user['location']
    for status in statuses
        for user in status['user'] ]

words = [ w
    for t in status_texts
        for w in t.split() ]

print json.dumps(status_texts[0:5], indent=1)
print json.dumps(screen_names[0:5], indent=1)
print json.dumps(hashtags[0:5], indent=1)
print json.dumps(location[0:5], indent=1)
```

The results are fine except for location. I got this error: line 63, in  for user in status['user'] ] TypeError: string indices must be integers [Finished in 1.4s with exit code 1].